# SQL tables join

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am looking for a way to fetch records in a single sql query for the complex joins. I have three tables lets say users, user_projects and appointments. User can be assigned to multiple projects and user can have multiple appointments on different dates.  How do I select all the users which is assigned to project1 and project2 and has appointments on date1 and date2? I am using postgres 9.5

Sample Data:

`users` table:

```
id, name    
1, Steve  
2, Bill  
3, Emma
```

`user_projects` table:

```
id, user_id, project_id  
1, 1, 1  
2, 2, 1  
3, 3, 1  
4, 1, 2
```

`appointments` table:

```
id, user_id, date  
1, 1, 2016-10-07  
2, 2, 2016-10-07  
3, 3, 2016-10-07  
4, 1, 2016-11-15  
5, 2, 2016-11-15
```

For this special case lets say I want to find all the users that belongs to project with id 1 and 2 and has appointment fixed on date 2016-10-07 and 2016-11-15. And the expected output is it should only include user with id 1 ie. Steve in this case

Comment: *I am looking for a better way*... that implies that you already have a working query. Can you post your existing SQL? Also, what database are you using?

Comment: I think it's simple join are looking for some special

Comment: What does your query look like so far?  And what flavor of SQL is this?

Comment: [edit] your question and the expected output based on your sample data.

Comment: This question should not have been closed -- it is 100% clear what is being asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT ID
FROM USERS U
JOIN (
  -- Users in two projects
  SELECT USER_ID 
  FROM USER_PROJECT
  WHERE PROJECT_ID = 1

  INTERSECTION

  SELECT USER_ID 
  FROM USER_PROJECT
  WHERE PROJECT_ID = 2
) UP ON U.ID = UP.USER_ID
JOIN (
  -- user ids that have appointments on two dates:
  SELECT USER_ID
  FROM APPOINTMENT 
  WHERE DATE = '2016-10-07'

  INTERSECTION

  SELECT USER_ID
  FROM APPOINTMENT 
  WHERE DATE = '2016-11-15'
) A ON U.ID = A.USER_ID
```

Another way to do it that should have the same performance (maybe this seems better because there are less lines?):

```
SELECT ID
FROM USERS U
JOIN (
  -- Users in two projects
  SELECT USER_ID 
  FROM USER_PROJECT
  WHERE PROJECT_ID IN (1,2)
  GROUP BY USER_ID
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT PROJECT_ID) =  2
) UP ON U.ID = UP.USER_ID
JOIN (
  -- user ids that have appointments on two dates:
  SELECT USER_ID
  FROM APPOINTMENT 
  WHERE DATE IN ('2016-10-07','2016-11-15')
  GROUP BY USER_ID
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT DATE) =  2
) A ON U.ID = A.USER_ID
```

Comment: Hogan how scalable this query will be if I have million of records on each one of the above tables

Comment: @user2250206 - it will be just fine if you put in the correct indexes.  If you don't have the correct indexes nothing will be "scalable".  There is not more "efficient" way to do this based on the rules you gave.  Is there additional data model information we can leverage to improve performance?  -- if not this is as fast as it is going to get.

Comment: I'd be interested to know why this was given a down vote -- please feel free to comment when you downvote.

Comment: @user2250206 - I posted another way to do it -- should take the same time.  But a given platform my prefer one to the other.

Comment: how the query will look like if one more condition is added, user who is assigned to project 1 and 2 or 3

Comment: @user2250206 - your question is totally ambiguous do you mean (1 and 2) or 3 -- 1 and (2 or 3), -- (1 and 2 and 3)

Comment: Sorry for confusion. It is (1 and 2) or 3. Actually, I am trying to build query language like jira query language (JQL https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira064/advanced-searching-720416661.html) where user can specify something like projects=(1 and 2) or (3)

Comment: @user2250206 - I see.  Your best bet is to use Andreas answer and make a new join for each filter then (as he did) use the where statement to apply the logic.  However, I'm not sure SQL is the right tool here -- I think most people these days would use a NOSQL product to implement such a system since it lends itself to the problem better.  If you look "under the hood" of JQL I expect you'd not find SQL there.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I'm missing something in the question. Looks like a simple join to me:

```
select distinct u.id
from users u
join user_projects up1 on u.id=up1.user_id
join user_projects up2 on u.id=up2.user_id
join appointments a1 on u.id=a1.user_id
join appointments a2 on u.id=a2.user_id
where up1.project_id = 1
and up2.project_id = 2
and a1.date = '2016-10-07'
and a2.date = '2016-11-15'
```

Here is a fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/415fd/1/0